# ERROR : 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.3.0'

Tags: java, android, maven, java-8, android-studio-3.0

build gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId ""
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 6
        versionName "1.5"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

repositories{
    maven {
        url  "http://dl.bintray.com/teads/TeadsSDK-android"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.1.0'

    implementation 'com.flurry.android:analytics:11.4.0@aar'

    //implementation 'com.flurry.android:analytics:8.2.0@aar'

    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.3.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'

    // Required dependency
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:12.0.1'

    // Teads SDK
    /*implementation ('tv.teads.sdk:androidsdk:2.5.12:fullRelease@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }*/

    // Teads SDK
    implementation("tv.teads.sdk.android:sdk:4.3.4@aar") {
        transitive = true
    }

    // Teads Admob Adapter
    implementation 'tv.teads.sdk.android:admobadapter:4.1.1'

    implementation 'org.apmem.tools:layouts:1.10@aar'
}
```

ERROR :

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: android.support.customtabs.ICustomTabsCallback","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
:app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\0.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\1.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\2.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\3.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\4.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\5.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\6.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\7.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\8.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\9.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\10.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\11.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\12.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\13.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\14.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\15.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\16.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\17.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\18.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\19.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\20.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\21.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\22.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\23.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\24.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\25.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\26.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\27.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\28.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\29.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\30.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\31.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\32.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\33.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\34.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\35.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\36.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\37.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\38.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\39.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\40.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\41.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\42.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\43.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\44.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\45.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\46.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\47.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\48.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\49.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\50.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\51.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\52.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\53.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\54.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\55.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\56.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\57.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\58.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\59.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\60.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\61.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\62.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\63.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\64.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\65.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\66.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\67.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\68.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\69.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\70.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\71.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\72.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\73.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\74.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\75.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\76.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\77.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\78.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\79.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\80.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\81.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\82.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\83.jar, D:\ANDROID\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\84.jar
```

Comment: use `play-services-ads:18.2.0`